# La funcion o el procedimiento tiene demasiados argumentos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2012

me ayudan con este error se produce si ejecuto un procedimiento almacenado mas de una vez en el siguiente proceso:
el error se produce dentro del foreach cuando entra por segunda vez

```
public string habilitarcredencial(int idusuariom, GridView sistemas, int reintentar)

{

string strsql;

strsql = "HabilitarCredencial";

CadenaConexion cc = new CadenaConexion();
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cc.ConnectionString());

SqlCommand da = new SqlCommand();
da.Connection = cnn;
cnn.Open();

da.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

string error = string.Empty;
string erroracumulador = string.Empty;

foreach (GridViewRow item in sistemas.Rows)

{

 TextBox boton = (TextBox)item.FindControl("FechaI");
 TextBox boto2 = (TextBox)item.FindControl("FechaF");

 if (boton.Text!="" && boto2.Text!="")
 {

 da.Parameters.Add("@idusuario", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idusuariom;
 da.Parameters.Add("@idsistema", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
 item.Cells[2].Text.ToString();
 da.Parameters.Add("@fechai", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = boton.Text;
 da.Parameters.Add("@fechan", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = boto2.Text;
 da.Parameters.Add("@reintentar", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = reintentar;

 da.Parameters.Add("@error", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000).Direction = 
 ParameterDirection.Output;

 da.CommandText = strsql;
 da.ExecuteNonQuery();
 erroracumulador = Convert.ToString(da.Parameters["@error"].Value);
 error = " "+error+" "+ erroracumulador +" ";
 } 

}

cnn.Close();

return error;
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar un poco mejor que error te da, cuándo y dónde? Así no se ve claro del todo y podremos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Te hace falta limpiar los parametros cada vez que iteras por el ciclo, de la forma actual en la que lo ejecutas por cada iteracion de `foreach`vueleve agregar parametros sin limpiar los anteriores por lo que solo agrega la siguiente linea al codigo

```
da.Parameters.Clear();
```

Quedando de la siguiente forma el ciclo:

```
foreach (GridViewRow item in sistemas.Rows)

{

 TextBox boton = (TextBox)item.FindControl("FechaI");
 TextBox boto2 = (TextBox)item.FindControl("FechaF");

 if (boton.Text!="" && boto2.Text!="")
 {

 da.Parameters.Add("@idusuario", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idusuariom;
 da.Parameters.Add("@idsistema", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
 item.Cells[2].Text.ToString();
 da.Parameters.Add("@fechai", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = boton.Text;
 da.Parameters.Add("@fechan", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = boto2.Text;
 da.Parameters.Add("@reintentar", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = reintentar;

 da.Parameters.Add("@error", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000).Direction = 
 ParameterDirection.Output;

 da.CommandText = strsql;
 da.ExecuteNonQuery();
 erroracumulador = Convert.ToString(da.Parameters["@error"].Value);
 error = " "+error+" "+ erroracumulador +" ";
 da.Parameters.Clear(); //Limpiamos los parametros
 } 

}
```

Saludos